# How can I move to the next screen after the splash screen is done in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, splash-screen, android-motionlayout

I made a splash screen with motion layout.
These are the codes.

[the splash screen xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxldv.png)

[the .kt file that has the splash screen ( 1/2 )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzTF5.png)

[the .kt file that has the splash screen ( 2/2 )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3TVd.png)

I am trying to move from MainActivity.kt(which is where the splash screen starts) to Intent_example2.kt.

I heard that that I have to deal with the Manifest.xml file, but I don't know the code for it.

Please help me , thank you.

Comment: Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: onTransitionCompleted()]

Here, you're trying to move from `MainActivity` to `MainActivity`.

Change

```
startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, MainActivity::class.java))
```

To

```
startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, Intent_example2::class.java))
```

And it should work fine.

Comment: @Abbas The snapshot I posted is originally from the question (there are links in the question you can see the image there). 
I just highlighted the mistake in the Activity classes in `startActivity()` and posted solution code with reference to the original code in the question. Please go through the snaps in the question.